# How can I check for null values in this linq query where clause

Tags: linq

I have a linq query to locate a matching item in a SharePoint library. It works fine if there is a custom property called 'MMSTerm' but if the property is null then obviously my string modifications will fail and error out when it hits x["MMSTerm"]

I will need to use string.replace in my where operation so a null won't be good.

```
SPListItem item = (from x in Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
                where x["MMSTerm"].ToString() == pageReference.ToString()
                select x).ToList<SPListItem>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Hopefully this is an easy one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify if field exists with [SPFieldCollection.ContainsField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.containsfield.aspx) method

```
SPListItem item = (from x in Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
                   where x.Fields.ContainsField("MMSTerm") && 
                         (x["MMSTerm"] == null ||
                          x["MMSTerm"].ToString() == pageReference.ToString())
                   select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also I think fluent API looks better in this case:

```
SPListItem item = Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => 
                           x.Fields.ContainsField("MMSTerm") &&
                          (x["MMSTerm"] == null ||
                           x["MMSTerm"].ToString() == pageReference.ToString()));
```

Comment: You can remove the `ToList<SPListItem>()` since it's pointless to create a new list just to throw it away immediately ;)

Comment: Thanks, Tim! Removed :) (ah that copy-paste from question to answer..)

Comment: I have tried the above but still getting 'object reference not set an instance of an object' - the field will always exist but it won't always have a value.

Comment: @ringo747 see update - I added null-check (all items with this field equal to `null` will match condition

Comment: I think I have missed giving you some detail. I want to return null if there is no matching item. The code seems to return an item. Should the || short-circuit the string comparison bit?

Comment: Sorted... used x["MMSTerm"] =! null &&
                          x["MMSTerm"].ToString() == pageReference.ToString())

Comment: @ringo747 sorry, was busy :) yes, if you want to ignore all items with field equal to null, then use `&&`. Otherwise `||`

Answer (score 1):

Since calling `x["MMSTerm"]` throws an exception when `"MMSTerm"` does not exist, rather than returning `null`, you should call [`ContainsField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.containsfield.aspx)

```
x.Fields.ContainsField("MMSTerm")
```

to see if the field is there:

```
SPListItem item = (from x in Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
            where x.Fields.ContainsField("MMSTerm") && x["MMSTerm"].ToString() == pageReference.ToString()
            select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Since `&&` short-circuits evaluation when `x.Fields.Contains("MMSTerm")` is `false`, the `x["MMSTerm"]` would not be evaluated.

In case the `x["MMSTerm"]` could contain `null`s, you could use the `""+obj` trick to avoid null reference exceptions:

```
var pageRefStr = pageReference.ToString();
SPListItem item = (from x in Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
            where x.Fields.ContainsField("MMSTerm") && pageRefStr.Equals(""+x["MMSTerm"])
            select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: But there's only a [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.contains.aspx) method which takes a `Guid`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are right, it should have been [`ContainsField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.containsfield.aspx). Thanks!